# Sending a notification from one user to another. php laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

For example, one user wants to send a message to another user. This message looks like an information box. The first user fills in this window and the second one should appear exactly the same. Tell me how you can do this or advise some kind of documentation. I'm new to laravel

Comment: https://pusher.com/tutorials/chat-laravel/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some service for sending it. you can choose from below:

- FCM notifications
- Websocket (Pusher Webosocket, Ratchet Websocket(easy one))

In these you can send data in JSON.

Thanks